# Solving $\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(xdx+ydy\right)+\left(x^2+y^2+2x+2y\right)\left(ydx-xdy\right)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the ODE $$\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(xdx+ydy\right)+\left(x^2+y^2+2x+2y\right)\left(ydx-xdy\right)=0$$
I think using differentiate is a good idea here. dividing the equation by $x^2+y^2$,

$$\frac12d(x^2+y^2)+(1+\frac{2x+2y}{x^2+y^2})(ydx-xdy)=0$$
Since $d(\frac xy)=\dfrac{ydx-xdy}{y^2}$, I decided to divide the equation by $y^2$,

$$\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{2y^2}+(1+\frac{2x+2y}{x^2+y^2}).d(\frac xy)=0$$

But it seems that doesn't help to write everything with differentiation.

Edit:

I just realized that I could use $d(\tan^{-1}(\frac yx))$
but it seems that doesn't work either.

Comment: Hint: This looks like an "exact equation". Write terms to group $dx$ and $dy$. Then proceed via the standard approach

Comment: Use polar coordinates, then you get $r^3dr-(r^2+2r(\cos\phi+\sin\phi))r^2d\phi=0$. Divide out $r^3$ and try to make sense of the remaining terms.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! I got your point.